# How to test the speed of an Authenticated Encryption algorithm?

Tags: authenticated-encryption

I am trying to implement Authenticated Encryption algorithms using CUDA. 
Most of Authenticated Encryption algorithms have  short message length like 64, 254..., 4094 (Byte). 
these message lengths are very short and their Enc/Dec times are very small.

consider an Intel-corei5-3337U ~1.80GHz CPU , and an algorithm that its Encryption speed for a 4096 Byte message is 0.48 cycle/byte. how many bytes this CPU Encrypts per second?

how should i test speed of the algorithm whether that is parallel or serial?

Comment: Take a look at SUPERCOP. It's a popular benchmark framework for CPU based benchmarking.

Comment: @CodesInChaos thanks for answer. Do you know a benchmark framework for windows?